# How to use ref in (conditional render)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements, render, ref

I want to use ref, however I am not able to use this in the conditional rendering which is initially false.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      filterActive: false,
    }
    this.firstRef = React.createRef();

}
```

If I use ref in this :-

```
{this.state.filterActive ?
    <label ref={this.firstRef}>Time Range</label>
:null}
```

The ref is null.

Comment: Not an answer, but you can rewrite your code as `{this.state.filterActive && <label ref={this.firstRef}>Time Range</label>}` - no need for the ternary operator returning `null` if false.

Comment: Hi @JamesWhiteley many thanks for your help. Actually this is just a dummy. I have a full section which needs to be rendered conditionally. Inside that section there are many elements and I want to use ref in one of those element.

Comment: When are you making `filterActive` state to true? Please share that code also.

Comment: on click of a button @RinkeshGolwala

Comment: Please share the complete component.

Answer (score 3):

How about something Like this:

```
// directly assign the element to this.firstRef
// instead of doing it in the constructor
    <label
      ref={(elem) => (this.firstRef = elem)}
      style={{display: this.state.filterActive ? 'inline-block' : 'none'}}
    >
      Time Range
    </label>
```

and when using this.firstRef you put you work inside an if like this:

```
if (this.firstRef) {
// your work
}
```

Comment: There are more elements which I can not show without condition is true, this is just an example. If I hide with css anybody will change the css and see those elements.

Comment: A normal user wouldn't have any idea about css. Wouldn't even know that you hid your element with css.

Comment: Anyways in order to get the element's ref the it has to be rendered. Therefore, I suggested to hid it with css.

Comment: Yes, but I can not do this with css.

Comment: Do you need the ref to do its work after or before the element renders?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem but I'm using hooks. I found an alternate solution. By using Intersection Observer, we can solve it.

**In Hooks, use 'useInView' hook from 'react-intersection-oberserver',**

// Use object destructing, so you don't need to remember the exact order

```
const { ref, inView, entry } = useInView(options);
```

// Or array destructing, making it easy to customize the field names

```
const [ref, inView, entry] = useInView(options);
```

Attach 'ref' to your DOM node, 'inView' will return a boolean whether your DOM node is in View or not and 'entry' will give access to DOM node properties.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useInView } from 'react-intersection-observer';
 
const Component = () => {
  const { ref, inView, entry } = useInView({
    /* Optional options */
    threshold: 0,
  });
 
  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      <h2>{`Header inside viewport ${inView}.`}</h2>
    </div>
  );
};
```

This fixed my problem.

For class based components, read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
render(){
 return(
{this.state.filterActive ? (<label ref={this.firstRef}>Time Range</label>) : (null)}
)}
```